# Getting input directly into a vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iostream

Consider the following code piece:

```
...
int N,var;
vector<int> nums;
cin >> N;
while (N--)
{
   cin >> var;
   nums.push_back(var);
}
...
```

Is it possible to do this without using an auxillary variable, in this case `var`?

Comment: What's wrong with using an auxiliary variable? You could limit its scope by declaring it inside the loop.

Comment: Not that anything is wrong with an auxiliary, I'm just curious if it is possible to without using one.

Comment: please make it clear - are you concerned about **performance**, **number of local variables** or **number of lines of code**? is the scenario exactly like on your listing or `N` could be unknown?

Comment: @Janusz, just for this case, i.e N is known. Also, I'm just interested in the number of local variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have already read the initial `N`, there is a nice trick using `istream_iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> nums;
nums.reserve(N);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(nums));
```

The `back_inserter` object turns itself into an iterator that adds elements to the vector at the end. Iterator streams can be parameterized by the type of the elements read, and, if no parameter given, signals the end of input.

Comment: This is not a trick, this is what `istream_iterator`s and the input iterator concept are for.

Comment: and why's it better to create auxiliary `back_inserter` object instead of auxiliary `int`? :D still, nice use of STL.

Comment: Since the vector has the space reserved & the 3rd parameter or std::copy needs to be an `OutputIterator` I believe you can pass `nums.begin()` directly instead of using a `back_inserter`.

Comment: @Eugen: Nice observation. Anyway, the two istream iterators are created anyway. However, I don't think the question was related to the overhead of just one integer, but with the possibility of not having to have the variable. I think that this functional-like approach is much more interesting.

Comment: @Diego: Just like you said, it was about the possibility of not having to have the variable. +1

Comment: @kolistivra: ehem.. here you've got at least three extra local variables! :D

Comment: @Janusz:Well, they are not explicitly allocated at least, but you are probably technically right =) Also, the trick itself is quite nice!

Comment: This code won't work. You initialize the vector with `N` elements of the default value, 0, and then `push_back()` beyond the `N` elements.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Good catch. The resultant vector would contain `N` zeroes followed by the actual input.

Comment: What it could be, is `std::vector<int> nums; nums.reserve(N);`

Comment: @SteveJessop yep. In fact that's more efficient than using the constructor in the case of non-primitive elements if you don't actually need `N` elements but just the defined behaviour in writing onto these positions.

Comment: @Steve: You're right. Corrected. You know, just thinking in the loop :)

Comment: If N is not given: std::vector<int> nums(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have already `copy_n()` in your toolbelt then you should. Very useful.

```
template<class In, class Size, class Out>
Out copy_n(In first, In last, Size n, Out result)
{
    while( n-- > 0 && first != last )
        *result++ = *first++;
    return result;
}
```

With this utility it's convenient and elegant to copy n elements into a vector:

```
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

// ...
int n = 0;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> v(n);
copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
       n,
       v.begin());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<int> nums(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin >> nums[i];
}
```

In the general case, this is actually more efficient.  Calling `std::vector::push_back()` repeatedly without an initial `reserve` will lead to lots of reallocations.

Comment: actually, `operator[]` is still checking for range abuse, so it's more efficient to strip vector to a C pointer and iterate :]

Comment: @Janusz: Indeed; but at least this won't ever be invoking a `resize`.

Comment: @Janusz: I thought `operator[]` doesn't do range checking, but `.at()` does?

Comment: @dreamlax, in MSVC implementation both check range, but you're partially right - `operator[]` doesn't if `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is off

Comment: Nice idea, but still using the extra variable i =) Of course this can be done with while(N--) kind of thing after coming up with idea of using the vector constructor..

Comment: @dreamlax: `operator[]` isn't *guaranteed* to range-check, obviously it's allowed to since exceeding the bounds is UB. If it is range-checking in an optimized build I think you're probably justified sending rude email to your compiler vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Hinted from Diego Sevilla answer.
Use a range constructor

```
std::vector<int> nums( std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                       std::istream_iterator<int>() );
```

Comment: How do I stop the input? Pressing `Enter` doesn't complete the input.

Comment: @MilindR ENTER followed by CTRL + D stops the input.

Answer (score 0):

No need to allocate the vector and then resize it.

Iterators are preferable to index usage.

```
size_t N;
std::cin >> N;

std::vector<int> values(N);
for (vector<int>::iterator iter = values.begin(); iter != values.end(); ++iter)
{
  std::cin >> *iter;
}
```